# Error for pointer to member in C++

Tags: c++

Header file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

const unsigned MaxLength = 11;

class Phone {
public:

    Phone(const char *phone) {
    setPhone(phone);
    }

    void        setPhone(const char Phone[ ]);
    const char* getPhone();

private:
    char phone[MaxLength+1];
};
```

Cpp file

```
#include "Phone.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std; 
bool checkNum(char num[]);

void Phone::setPhone(const char Phone[ ]) {
    strncpy(phone, Phone, MaxLength);
    phone[MaxLength] = '\0';
}

const char* Phone::getPhone() {
    return phone;
}


int main() {
    Phone i1("12345678901");

    cout << i1.getPhone() << endl;
    if (checkNum(i1.getPhone)) 
        cout << "Correct" << endl;
    else 
        cout << "Invalid Wrong" << endl;

}

bool checkNum(char num[]) {
    bool flag = true;
        if (isdigit(num[0]) == 0)
            flag = false;
    return flag;
}
```

When I tried to compile, I get this error:

> error C3867: 'Phone::getPhone':
>   function call missing argument list;
>   use '&Phone::getPhone' to create a
>   pointer to member

I'm getting an error on this line "if (checkNum(i1.getPhone))". I created a Phone object and what I am trying to do is use the function checkNum to see if the first index of the array is a number. Am I referencing the object wrong? Should I use indirect selection operator instead? Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a pair of parentheses after `getPhone` in `if (checkNum(i1.getPhone))`; it should be `if (checkNum(i1.getPhone()))`.

Comment: omg... I was looking over this code for so long..kept passing this without noticing. haha thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
if (checkNum(i1.getPhone))
```

should be

```
if (checkNum(i1.getPhone()))
```